# Asp mvc razor store value of input file in textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in my view, I need to store name of selected file from the input file in the textbox above, I have tried the following JS script but I get no results

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.helpVM.str1, htmlAttributes:new { id="inputId", @class = "form-control" })

<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('fileID').onchage(); return false;" class="btn btn-info">Choisir fichier</a>
     <input type="file" name="FileUpload" accept=".txt" data-input="false"  id="fileID" style="visibility: hidden;" />
 </div>  


            <script type="text/javascript">
                var filename = $('#fileID').val();
                document.getElementById("fileID").onchange = function () {
                    document.getElementById("inputId").value = filename
                };
```

In fire bug i get this error TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onchange is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use Change event, not click. and the syntax should be like this:

```
document.getElementById("fileID").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("inputId").value = this.value;
}
```

**update:**

well I suggest you to change your code as below :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" onclick="HandleIt();" class="btn btn-info">Choisir fichier</a>
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" accept=".txt" data-input="false"  id="fileID" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</div>  


<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleIt(){            
        document.getElementById("fileID").onchange = function () {
            document.getElementById("inputId").value = this.value;
        };
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Redadublex : sorry , fixed the syntax

Comment: still no result it's an input file, i need to get name of the file in the textbox

Comment: @Redadublex : Check it now. I knew there is a problem with the syntax

Comment: That seems to work fine, my probleme now is instead of getting file name, i get "undifined" in my textbox

Comment: your first solution worked perfect, just some misunderstanding thank you for helping

Answer (score 3):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("fileID").onchange = function () {
        document.getElementById("inputId").value= this.value;
    }     
</script>
```

Comment: it doesnt work, it gives me this error in fire bug "TypeError: ev.popupWindowURI is null"